# I do not receive any payload from trello when my webhook is triggered

Tags: php, webhooks, trello

I created a webhook in trello for a list:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/$TRELLO_TOKEN/webhooks/ \
-d '{
  "key": "$TRELLO_API_KEY",
  "callbackURL": "https://at.foobar.com/trello-whook.php",
  "idModel":"5d9511856b7586142414762b",
  "description": "My first webhook"  
}'
```

As answer I got:

```
{"id":"5dc9cded49bf251341c6d32c","description":"My first webhook","idModel":"5d9511856b7586142414762b","callbackURL":"https://at.foobar.com/trello-whook.php","active":true,"consecutiveFailures":0,"firstConsecutiveFailDate":null}%
```

My webhook get triggered when I add/delete cards on this list. When I understood the [documentation](https://developers.trello.com/page/webhooks) correct, I should get a HTTP POST with JSON to my webhook. But I do not see any payload in my log file...

Here is my `trello-webhook.php` code:

```
<?php
ini_set( "log_errors", 1);
ini_set( "error_log", "/var/log/trello-scripts.log");
error_log(  "trello-whook was called" );
$output = print_r( $_POST, true );
error_log( $output );
?>
```

And here is the output of my `/var/log/trello-scripts.log`:

```
[11-Nov-2019 21:25:54 UTC] trello-whook was called
[11-Nov-2019 21:25:54 UTC] Array
(
)
```

Where do I have a missunderstanding? How do I get the trello JSON?

Comment: try print_r($_REQUEST) and see maybe something helpful is there

Comment: @PavelLint Same result with `print_r($_REQUEST) `: An empty `Array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pick up the payload by using:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```